# How do I specify a metatext/description for a section?

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I want to add like a meta text or a description for my sections. E.g.

```
\section{Components}
In this section I am going to write a little about the components in the system.


Main text about components comes here...
```

Comment: Would you please point at an example of what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new environment like this:

```
\newenvironment{sectionmeta}%
{\textbf{$\hookrightarrow$}\begin{itshape}}
{\end{itshape}}
```

and use it in your .tex file like this:

```
\section{Components}

\begin{sectionmeta}
In this section I am going to write a little about the components in the system.
\end{sectionmeta}
\vspace{5mm}
\par \lipsum[1]
```

[image: Implementing section meta in LaTeX]

Comment: No, thats not what I'm looking for, that removes the text entirely. It is common in academic litterature to give a small description about the text that is comming, in order to prepare the reader. This is referred to as "text that describes the text", meta data so to speak.